# How to programmatically delete an email from list of bounced emails?

Tags: python, python-requests, sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3, sendgrid-api-v2

I am working on a GAE(Google App Engine) based python app and which have sendgrid python SDK(v3.2.10) integrated into it. What I am trying do is right now that whenever sendgrid pushes an event webhook of type "bounce" I want to delete that bounced email from the list of bounced emails present on sendgrid.

I have already gone through the documentation provided on the official site. First I tried to delete email address using SDK and it worked fine on localhost. But after deploying it to the live server it just doesn't do anything and falls in the exception clause.

Code snippet:

```
try:
    send_grid_client = sendgrid.SendGridAPIClient(apikey=SENDGRID_API_KEY)
    data = {"emails": [email.strip()]}
    delete_response = send_grid_client.client.suppression.bounces.delete(
                                    request_body=data)
except Exception as exception:
    logging.info('Exception is: {}'.format(exception))
    pass
```

As it did not work as expected, I am now trying to do the same using REST API.

Code snippet:

```
import requests
data = {"emails": [email]}
headers = {"Authorization": "Bearer {}".format(SENDGRID_API_KEY)}
delete_response = requests.delete("https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/suppression/bounces", data=json.dumps(data), headers=headers)
logging.info(delete_response)
logging.info(delete_response.status_code)
logging.info(delete_response.text)
```

Now, sendgrid API is continuously returning error 400 with message `{"errors":[{"field":null,"message":"emails or delete_all params required"}]}`. I simply could not figure out how to overcome this issue. Maybe I am missing how to pass request body in the `delete` function but, I could not figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figured out the issue.

It's the SendGrid API docs [here](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Web_API_v3/bounces.html) which causes confusion as it is not mentioned clearly that they have a different way of calling the same endpoint when you want to delete a single email address or list of emails.

For a single email, it needs to be passed in the URL i.e. `https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/suppression/bounces/{email_address}`

For a list of emails, the list needs to be passed in the body of the delete request. i.e. it will look like this `{"emails": [email_address_1, email_address_1, ...]}`

As in the question above a single email was meant to be deleted and it was being passed as `{"emails": [email_address_1]}` in the delete request. Sendgrid API was not able to digest this info and was throwing an error. The email address was to be passed in the URL.

This issue has been resolved. But, I wonder why Sendgrid API was not able to digest this info `{"emails": [email_address_1]}`. Why they have a hard assumption that list will always have elements greater than one in it.